# Android source base: where is partition table defined

Tags: android

In the Android system source base, where is the partition table specified? I realize that this is vendor/device-specific.

Comment: it's been awhile, but any luck finding where those small partitions are defined?

Comment: Nah, I'm afraid it's been way too long since I worked on this stuff for me to remember if I ever did get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The partition sizes are defined in the board configuration files.  For example, the system partition size is `BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE`, defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/asus/flo/+/master/BoardConfigCommon.mk) for flo and [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/asus/grouper/+/master/BoardConfigCommon.mk) for grouper.

Mapping code names to products is a separate issue.  (IIRC, grouper and flo are the Nexus 7 (2012) and Nexus 7 (2013), respectively.)

Comment: I see the definitions for the standard Android partitions (system, userdata, cache, recovery, persist), but what about the others? Such as boot, or the dozen other device-specific partitions that vendors add?

Comment: Thanks for your info. If I want to increase cache partition size, altering values in BoardConfig.mk is sufficient? I heard that the bootloader should be modified too!